# Remove language slug from site assets url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need some help with htaccess

I have site structure:

```
root
-- /script
-- /css
-- /images
-- /en
-- /en/contact.html
-- /de
-- /de/kontakten.html
```

1.
I want that if no **/en** or **/de** is added to example.com, then it should redirect to **example.com/en**

2.
Link should be accessible with 
**example.com/en/contact**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/(de|en)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/en/$1 [R]
#2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
#3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (\/de|\/en)
RewriteRule (\/de|\/en) / [L]
```

Now the problem is that .css, .js, images have links like this
http://www.example.com**/en**/script/functions.js 
(**/en** or **/de** is added)

Does somebody have idea how to remove /en, /de from assets url?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule after first `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: I added this file check, works perfectly. I cant imagine how could I forgot this. Thank you :)